# How do I sort a WPF TreeView using the HierarchicalDataTemplate for EntityCollection objects?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, sorting, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

My *Webpage* is an Entity Framework entity. These are bound to a WPF TreeView. I want to order all the *Webpages* shown in the TreeView on the *Sort* property.

### Code

**EDMX**

[image: Entity Framework EDMX entity]

Its *Subordinates* property returns a collection of zero or more *Webpages*.

**XAML**

```
<TreeView Name="TreeViewWebpages">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Webpage}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Subordinates}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

**C#**

```
TreeViewWebpages.ItemsSource = from Webpage root in db.Webpages.Include("Subordinates")
                               where root.Dominant == null
                               select root;
```

### Result

*Webpages* are unordered within the TreeView.

### Problem

How do I change this to order all the *Webpages* shown in the TreeView on the *Sort* property?

---

## Update

This ValueConverter seems to work (Thank you @KP Adrian and @IVerzin). Is there a better way?

**XAML**

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Subordinates, Converter={local:SortConverter}}"
```

**C#**

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(EntityCollection<Webpage>), typeof(EntityCollection<Webpage>))]
public class SortConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((EntityCollection<Webpage>)value).OrderBy(o => o.Sort);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to sort both top-level and subordinate-level pages, use a value converter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722835/how-to-sort-treeview-items-using-sortdescriptions-in-xaml

Comment: Yes, EntityCollection<T> does not implement IList, but you could cast value to an instance of your EntityCollection<WebPage> and call ToList() on it. -- System.Collections.IList collection = (value as EntityCollection<WegPage>).ToList();

Comment: Note that this will only work effectively if you have a single HierarchicalDataTemplate. If you have multiple HierarchicalDataTemplate selected by the DataType atrribute, using this method will sort the list multiple times which may slow things down. I haven't yet found a solution to bypass this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Sort property is a string or integer you are using to determine the order at runtime, you can add an **orderby** section to your expression.

```
TreeViewWebpages.ItemsSource = from Webpage root in db.Webpages.Include("Subordinates")
                           where root.Dominant == null
                           orderby root.Sort
                           select root;
```

Comment: This doesn't order subordinates. Or subordinates of subordinates.

Comment: You didn't mention you wanted to sort at all levels. I'd recommend a value converter solution as I commented above.