# Sorting subitems of a TreeView in WPF when editing them

Tags: wpf, binding, refresh, listcollectionview

I have a 2 levels TreeView that is filled with a collection items that each one has another  collection of items.

```
class A
{
    public List<B> collection;
}

List<A> treeViewCollection;
```

I'm using a ListCollectionView to sort these items using a converter in the case of the collection inside the collection as recommended here:

[How to sort TreeView items using SortDescriptions in Xaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722835/how-to-sort-treeview-items-using-sortdescriptions-in-xaml)

The problem that I've found is that the ListCollectionView does not resort the items when they are edited so I've created my own ListCollectionView class to attach to the items property notification. What I don't know is what to do now when I detect that an item has changed to resort the ListCollectionView. If I call Refresh() on the ListCollectionView I lose the selection at the TreeView, I've seen somewhere about raising the CollectionChangedNotification with a Replace action (and that sounds as a good idea to me) but it has no effect on the TreeView.

Any idea on how to update the TreeView sorting without losing all the selections and expanded items?

Thanks.