# How to sort a DataTemplate in a TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, collectionviewsource

I have a list of *Features* and every *Feature* has a list of *Fields*.
I was able to display them accordingly with the help of the `TreeView` control.

**-Feature1**
 -FieldMemberA
 -FieldMemberB
**-Feature2**
  -FieldMemberX

Now I would like to sort the *Features* list and the *Fields* list. Sorting the *Features* list worked with the`CollectionViewSource`. However, I couldnt apply the same for the *Fields* list.

I copied the working code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Features}" x:Key="SortedFeatures">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <componentModel:SortDescription Direction="Descending" PropertyName="Prop1"/>
            <componentModel:SortDescription Direction="Ascending" PropertyName="Prop2"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>     
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedFeatures}}">               
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}" DataType="{x:Type model:Feature}">   
                    <RadioButton Name="IsSelectedRadioButton" Content="{Binding Path=FeatureName}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" GroupName="selectedFeatureGroup"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Field}"> 
                    <CheckBox Name="CriteriaCheckBox" Content="{Binding Path=FieldName}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
                </DataTemplate >
            </TreeView.Resources>     
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
```

What I have tried is something like:

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Fields}" x:Key="SortedFields">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <componentModel:SortDescription Direction="Descending" PropertyName="Prop1"/>
            <componentModel:SortDescription Direction="Ascending" PropertyName="Prop2"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
```

under `<TreeView.Resources>` and binding to `SortedFields` instead of `Fields`.

Comment: Look at this question to find a possible solution for your problem (using a IValueConverter to generate CollectionViews dynamically): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722835/how-to-sort-treeview-items-using-sortdescriptions-in-xaml?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @Miiite would you be so kind to enlighten me why this is a silly question? I' m searching for a pure XAML solution. Thus, no OrderBy, ThenBy will work for my. The IValueConverter solution seems to work only with one parameter. I need a least two.

Comment: In that case I would suggest `IMultiValueConverter`. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx)

Comment: Try moving the DataType to the CollectionViewSource.

Comment: I guess you're looking for something like this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5730402/364429)